# Angular Material Mat-Menu overlay not growing in height when Mat-chip-autocomplete is opened inside it

Tags: css, angular, typescript, angular-material

I'm trying to create a Mat-Menu component and inside the menu, I have created a MAT-CHIP-AUTOCOMPLETE. The problem which I m facing is, when the Mat-chip-autocomplete, opens, the mat menu doesn't grow in height and it opens outside, the menu. I want the mat-chip autocomplete to open inside the mat-menu and also grow in height. Can someone please help me on this issue.

Also attaching the StackBlitz [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3tqhe1-73imzg?file=src%2Findex.html)

A screen shot is given below:

[image]

Comment: I guess static CSS is not what you are looking for  `.cdk-overlay-pane {
    height: calc(100% - 405px);
    }`

Comment: the Mat-menu-module takes mat-menu-item element as a menu item.
I haven't seen it being used like this. [link]https://material.angular.io/components/menu/api